# Differential copy

Tags: windows, backup, network-shares

I have a shared folder where files are saved and/or updated in different sub folders using a third party application.
I am looking for an open source program that will let me try to do an differential backup to another shared folder at preset times.

Comment: Why are you asking for Open Source support? I only ask because some people really don't care if software is open source, just that it is free (as in beer). Are closed source solutions acceptable as long as they have no cost?

Comment: That is pretty much it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For windows most people use Robocopy, which is part of the windows server resource kit. unfourtunately its not OSS, but it is free and easy to obtain. 
http://burpee.smccme.edu/studenthowtos/robocopy.htm

Comment: Actually, it comes built in to Vista or later. You only need to download the resource kit for XP.